# firebird database migrating from windows XP to windows 7

Tags: database, odbc, firebird

I have changed my operating system from windows XP to windows 7. I installed firebird 1.5.3.4870 and driver firebird odbc 1.2.0.69 on windows 7. But when I go to ODBC Data Source Administrator -> drivers I cannot see firebird driver. When I install new version of firebird driver I see it on data source administrator but I can't open old databases. Is it possible to open firebird databases created on win xp in windows 7.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with 'can't open old databases'?

Comment: database which was created on windows XP

Comment: I meant more how does the problem manifest itself, what error do you get, etc.

Comment: It is OK. I already have an answer I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you migrated from Windows XP 32 bit to Windows 7 64 bit you will have to backup (on Windows XP!) and restore the database (on Windows 7), as the database structure of Firebird database before 2.1 (I think, could be 2.0) are not transportable between 32 bit and 64 bit architectures without backup/restore.

Also be aware that Firebird 1.5 is not compatible with Windows 7 (it was never tested under Windows Vista and Windows 7), so you might want to upgrade to Firebird 2.5.1 as well (although you might want to test that first).